# ¿Cómo abro un proyecto de Homestead con Sublime Text en Ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, xubuntu

Instalé Vagrant en Ubuntu (Xubuntu para ser exacto), todo funciona bien, he podido ejecutar el proyecto. Mi problema es que no logro encontrar el directorio con mi proyecto. Les muestro imágenes para más descriptivo:

[image: Mis tres proyectos creados en la ante penúltima línea]

[image: Configuración del fichero Homestead.yaml]

[![Intentando acceder al directorio desde el OS host][3]][3]

[![Aquí la prueba de que todo funciona bien][4]][4]

Todo carga bien, cuando intento acceder directamente a:

```
cd /home/vagrant/Code/Proyecto
```

Simplemente no accede, no se encuentra la ubicación y esto porque asumo que esa es la ruta dentro de servidor virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente esta pregunta solo la podría responder yo y esto es lo que ocurrió:

Cuando instalé el entorno de Homestead con Vagrant, definí una carpeta ~/Code que no existía, luego, dentro de la máquina virtual **creé manualmente el directorio /home/vagrant/Code **. Luego Salí de mi máquina virtual y recién creé el directorio /home/ricky/Code. De esta forma no había referencias entre uno y otro directorio porque estamos hablando de dos directorios diferentes.

**¿Cómo me di cuenta de esto?**
Instalé nuevamente y paso a paso Vagrant y Homestead en la computadora de mi trabajo. El proceso fue el siguiente:

1. Instalar Virtualbox (en mi caso).
2. Instalar Vagrant
3. Crear la caja: vagrant box add laravel/homestead
4. [Clonar el Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead)
5. Ingresar al directorio creado al clonar.
6. Ejecutar el siguiente comando bash init.sh (Linux y Windows)
7. Configurar el archivo Homestead.yaml
8. Crear claves ssh usando git: ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "tu@email.com"
9. levantar Vagrant: vagrant up
10. Ingresar a la máquina: vagrant ssh

Si haces algún cambio en el archivo Homestead.yaml ejecutar: **vagrant provision**, y luego ejecutar los pasos 9 y 10.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como se ve en la segunda imagen que compartes, en la configuración de Homestead estás "mapeando" el directorio `~/Code` de tu máquina "real" a `/home/vagrant/Code` en tu máquina virtual.

Así que básicamente puedes acceder en tu máquina el directorio compartido de esta manera:

```
cd /home/{nombre usuario}/Code
```

o si no sabes cual es tu nombre de usuario (?):

```
cd
cd Code
```

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo extraño, sí conozco mi username pero cuando accedo a la ruta que mencionas no existe el directorio Code: /home/ricky/Code, sin embargo cuando ingreso a homested por vagrant sí encuentro mis proyectos...

Comment: Bueno, quisiera ser más exacto en mi comentario anterior. El directorio Code dentro de mi username sí existe (porque yo lo creé manualmente, dado que si no existe me aparece un mensaje rojo diciendo que hay un error de configuración), pero está vacío, no hay data ni cuando hago un ls -a

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero ya se cual es mi problema, lo voy a detallar en la respuesta.